# JQuery Datatable serverside processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatable version 1.10.16 and I have serverside processing true, but I have problem with setting total pages and total number of records, when I use:

```
 public class DTResponse<T>
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }
        public int iRecordsTotal { get; set; }
        public int iRecordsDisplay { get; set; }
        public SampleRow[] data { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

Datatable shows no rows, I had fnServerData as below:

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
                    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                        "url": sSource,
                        "data": aoData,
                        "success": fnCallback,
                        "headers": { "Authorization": ...... }
                    });
                }
```

what is correct viewmodel or table setting to overcome this situtaion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, In datatables.min.js that I have has been written:

```
 * To rebuild or modify this file with the latest versions of the included
 * software please visit:
 *   https://datatables.net/download/#dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.4.2/b-html5-1.4.2
 *
 * Included libraries:
 *   DataTables 1.10.16, Buttons 1.4.2, HTML5 export 1.4.2
 */

/*!
 DataTables 1.10.16
 ©2008-2017 SpryMedia Ltd - datatables.net/license
*/
```

But weirdly when using serverside it sends legacy parameters and when receives response as legacy response, it works correctly.